# Mailgun Attachment + Axios

Tags: reactjs, email, axios, attachment, mailgun

I would like to send an attachment with Mailgun using react+axios.

Currently, I get an email with an attachment, but it is not named correctly (the name is ".") and if I rename it to a text file it contains the text "[object Object]".
Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

```
const form = new FormData();

const fs = require("fs");

form.append("from", "example@gmx.ch");
form.append("to", "Bob <example@hotmail.ch>");
form.append("subject", "Test");
form.append("text", "Hello!!");
form.append("attachment", [{
    filename: "example.txt",
    data: fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/text.txt", {
        encoding: "utf8",
        flag: "r"
    })
}]);

const endpoint = "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox123.mailgun.org/messages";

await axios.post(endpoint, form, {
    auth: {
        username: "api",
        password: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY
    },
    headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. As per the [mailgun docs](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#sending) when sending attachments you must use "multipart/form-data" encoding. Try:

```cpp
await axios.post(endpoint, form, {
    auth: {
        username: "api",
        password: process.env.MAILGUN_API_KEY
    },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }
 });
```

2. Try putting your attachment object inside an array. I am not familiar with the mailgun API but I saw a couple examples where the attachments were inside an array, maybe even if there is a single attachment the API is still expecting it this way.

Comment: Thank you very much, but it hasn't changed anything - the result is still the same.